# Answer Right in Front of Me? (Generic.List requires a model item of type Generic.IEnumerable Error)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Ok I've been wrestling this for days and I don't really seem to be getting very far. I'm sure people are sick of seeing questions relating to this type of error as there are loads on here and I've gone through loads however I can't seem to piece all of the answers together for a complete solution for my scenario.

I'll start off by posting my code...

**Controller - HomeController.cs (Child Action)**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Widget()
    {
        var eventId = ViewEventPropertyService.Get().Select(y => new { y.EventId }).ToList();

        return PartialView("Widget", eventId);
    }
```

*I can see by using the debugger that the above retrieves the results I expect*

**Model - Event.cs**

```
public partial class Event : Auditable
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public Event()
    {
        this.Parents = new List<EventRelationship>();
        this.Children = new List<EventRelationship>();
        this.Properties = new List<EventProperty>();
        this.ViewProperties = new List<ViewEventProperty>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

*I'm not sure how relevant the above is for the question but I thought I'd include it just in cse*

**ViewModel - EventDetailsViewModel.cs**

```
public class EventDetailsViewModel : IEnumerable<Solution.Domain.Event>
{
    public IEnumerable EventId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Solution.Domain.Event> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

*I put the **GetEnumertor** parts in based on an answer from another question but I'm not really sure if it's right.*

**View - index.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("Widget")
```

*I just call the above in a view, I don't think any other information is needed (let me know if it is though).*

**Partial View - Widget.cshtml**

```
    @model IEnumerable<Solution.Web.Models.EventDetailsViewModel>
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>@item.EventId</div>
        }
    HTML.Display
</body>
</html>
```

*I think the above is correct to list the results but I'm not 100%*

**My Aim**

Ok so what I am trying to do is just list the EventIds from the database that is picked up by the **Widget()** child action on to a view.

**My Issue**

With my current code I get the following error message.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType22`1[System.Int32]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Solution.Web.Models.EventDetailsViewModel]'.

I can see that the error is saying that the action is returning a **Generic.List** and I'm asking for a **IEnumerable** but I don't know how to return the data so that it is of this type.

So, can anyone help me with this as I'm getting nowhere now...?

This question is long enough now so I'll leave it there but if anyone requires any more detail then just ask.

Thank you

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are implementing `IEnumerable<Solution.Domain.Event>` in `EventDetailsViewModel`, maybe I'm missing the bigger picture here. In order to resolve the specific issue of incorrect model type you can make such changes:

First, simplify the view model (and change Id type to int):

```
public class EventDetailsViewModel
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

And second - use this type in your controller method instead of anonymous object:

```
public ActionResult Widget()
{
    var eventIds = ViewEventPropertyService.Get()
        .Select(y => new EventDetailsViewModel { EventId = y.EventId })
        .ToList();
    return PartialView("Widget", eventIds);
}
```

Comment: You absolute saviour!! That sorted it straight away. I can't believe you resolved it that quickly when I've been going in circles for days. Thank you so much, it's very appreciated.